# data sharing @input - child component not showing parent property

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm practicing d various data sharing methods. Here i'm doing simple parent to child data sharing but not able to use/show the parent (count) value in child view..

### Parent Component

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({
      selector: 'app-parent',
      template: '<app-child [parentCount]="count"></app-child>',
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
    })
    export class ParentComponent{
      count :number = 10;

    }
```

### Child Component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template:'<div>{{parentCount}}</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() 
  parentCount:number;

  constructor(){
    //console.log(this.parentCount);
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code should work as it is, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-31jwuo). If you put some hard coded text in the child template (e.g. `<div>I am the child</div>`), can you see it? If not, the problem may be in your CSS.

Comment: no..it's empty CSS file./child not showing anything..

Comment: More questions: if you put hard coded text in the parent template, do you see it? Did you import the components in the module? Do you see errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Do it inside ngOninit instead of inside a constructor as follows

```
export class ChileComponent {
    @Input()
    parentCount: number;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('The value we are receiving here is: ' + this.parentCount);
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdnjf5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You will get the value in ngOnChanges Hook. Use the below code in child component.

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template:'<div>{{parentCount}}</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() 
  parentCount:number;

  constructor(){
    //console.log(this.parentCount);
   }

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log(changes.parentCount.currentValue);

}

}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I would just include an if to check for changes.parentCount && chnages.parentCount.currentValue. It makes it more efficient and more future proof.

Comment: you do not need ngChanges since OP just need to pass the value

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the value from html

```
<app-child [parentCount]="count"></app-child>
```